# How to clean listitem data in ListActivity when using extends BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyway to clean listitem data inside `ListActivity` and then show data using  `setListAdapter`(adapter) ? The problem is it continuously appends listitem data inside ListActivity and show many listitem data. I used android.widget.SimpleAdapter for adapter. I want to clean data and then show data.

```
class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              ........

            }   
            setListAdapter(adapter);  
        }   
    }
```

Comment: how did u instantiate the SimpleAdapter (which parameters) ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i use android.widget.SimpleAdapter. it nvr refresh.

class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...

        }   
        setListAdapter(adapter);  
    }   
}